# How do you access a label's ID from JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an event listener for some checkboxes:

```
$('.table-sticky-container').on('click', 'label', function() {
  console.log(this);
})
```

This logs: < label id="checkbox,0">...</label

How do I access this id? I would like it to console "checkbox,0". I'm not sure about the syntax. I tried this.id, this('label[id]]') and bunch of other stuff. Anybody know?
Thank you.

Comment: `this.getAttribute('id')` should work https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: @GrafiCode `getAttribute()` isn't wrong, but it's unnecessary. See my answer below.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you're right. Since OP is using jQuery, even `$(this).attr('id')` would work, but your solution is the most performant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By accessing the `id` property of `this`:

```js
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
  console.log(this.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<lable id="foo">Test</label>
```